# How to define own directory previewer in ranger filemanager

Tags: linux, file-manager

The `ranger` filemanager supports implementing of file preview (via `~/.config/ranger/scope.sh` config). But it only works for the files.

Is there a possibility to implement my own directory previewer?
I want to change the area that is shown in the screenshot. For example, I want to see some custom statistic (or preview particular file, etc) in selected directory instead of list of files.
[image]